# Any Linux Distros that may work well with intel 965gm gpu?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, intel, gpu

My mom's laptop had ubuntu 12.04 32bit and now 13.10.
But they both are extremely slow. makes windows xp look super fast. (which was on it  before)

on askubuntu they said the gpu is the issue.

Lenovo ThinkPad R61e:

CPU - Pentium Dual Core t2370 1.73ghz x 2

Ram - 1GB DDR2 667mhz

GPU - intel 965gm x86/mmx/sse2

HDD - 80gb sata

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is more with the choice of [desktop shell](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) than with the distribution itself. The Intel graphics drivers for Linux tend to be quite mature, thanks to [Intel involvement](http://01.org/linuxgraphics/), so there probably isn't much of an absolute performance gain to be had by changing distributions.

If your hardware doesn't meet the [recommended hardware requirements](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements) for Unity, you've ruled out any [OpenGL issues](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements), and your mom can live without fancy desktop effects such as transparent windows provided by the underlying [compositing manager](http://www.compiz.org/), you might want to try [Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop), which provides a [near-identical user experience](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D) as the regular Unity, sans desktop effects.

Unity 2D uses [Metacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacity) as its window manager, which is also the window manager used by GNOME 2. There are also many other [lightweight window managers](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_Manager), many of which are available in Ubuntu.

Comment: You could also consider Lubuntu which is designed for computers with lower specs.

Answer (score 0):

Given the spec of the machine and the fact you are using unity, as previously answered I think the shell is your problem and not the underlying system. Depending on use and how comfortable you are with Linux command line I'd suggest looking at Crunchbang Linux, it's still based on Debian as Ubuntu is so the command line is much the same but it uses the Openbox desktop environment which is very lightweight. The only thing that might be an issue at first is the lack of a menu button (right click on desktop for menu).

I've got an IBM X61s which uses Intel X3100 graphics, an Intel Core 2 Duo SV T7300 and which admittedly does have 3Gb of ram (but Crunchbang never uses more than 1Gb in normal use) and it's nice and snappy on that. I've also run it on a Samsung Netbook with a 1.6Ghz Atom processor and it runs well on that.

My wife is a bit of a technophobe but she quite happily uses my X61s for web browsing so your Mum should be able to adapt to it quite easily.